# Keep homepage redirect, but change http to https sitewide (including subdomains)

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect, ssl

I checked other htaccess questions and answers but nothing seemed to work for this situation.

The code below is my current htaccess file. There's a redirect of the homepage that's in place, that I need to keep. I have SSL keys and certificates for the site and I just need to get the http changed to https.

I'm sure it's not complicated, this is just out of my current knowledge.

Please help!

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|admin|gadgets|images|editor|user_guide|captcha|system|css|utils|src|themes|tools|xinha|uploads|js|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*).html /$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^startuptoolshop\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.startuptoolshop\.com$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "http\:\/\/startuptoolshop\.com\/index\.php\/categories" [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Insert this rule just below `RewriteEngine on`

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 0):

Put this code in .htaccess file :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```